# Do JavaScript property descriptors support custom attributes?

Tags: javascript

I would like to define a JavaScript property using a property descriptor that has custom attributes, in other words, attributes other than the standard `value`, `writable`, etc...

In the example below I have defined a property with a property descriptor that has the custom attribute `customAttr`. The call to `Object.defineProperty` works fine but later when I try to loop over the attributes of the property descriptor, my custom attribute is not listed.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

```js
const o = {}

Object.defineProperty(o, 'newDataProperty', {
  value: 101,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
  customAttr: 1,
})

const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'newDataProperty')

// List the descriptor attributes.
for (const prop in desc) {
  console.log(`${prop}: ${desc[prop]}`)
}

// PROBLEM: `customAttr` is not listed
```

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this?

Comment: hi james... please see the comment i entered below under your answer... at run time i would like to loop over all of the object's properties, check to see which ones are "decorated" with certain attributes, and based on the existence, absence, and values of those attributes, then proceed to do "things" like validation of the property... thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible. This is what [`Object.defineProperty`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.6) does:

> ...
>
> 3. Let *desc* be the result of calling `ToPropertyDescriptor` with *Attributes* as the argument.
>
> 4. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *O* with arguments *name*, *desc*, and true.
>
> 5. Return *O*.

And in short, [`ToPropertyDescriptor`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.10.5) simply ignores anything that's not "enumerable", "writable", "configurable", "value", "get" or "set":

> 1. ...
> 2. Let *desc* be the result of creating a new Property Descriptor that initially has no fields.
> 3. If the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of *Obj* with argument "`enumerable`" is true, then
>
>    - ...
>
> (repeat step 3 for other valid descriptor properties)
>
> 10. Return *desc*.

Comment: thank you... what a shame... there must be good reasons for this limitation i guess... but it closes the door to many things... i am currently generating JS code from C# code. I have C# properties that are decorated with attributes... i would like to bring these attributes over to the JS code... when i first looked into JS property descriptors i was like "excellent, this is just what i need"... oh well... still loving the JS though...

Answer (score 4):

Resurrecting an old post here, but I found the idea interesting. You can extract the fact that functions are objects in javascript, and use the `get` function as the attribute holder :

```
function setPropertyAttribute(obj, propertyName, attributeName, attributeValue) {
  var descriptor = getCustomPropertyDescriptor(obj, propertyName);

  descriptor.get.$custom[attributeName] = attributeValue;
}

function getPropertyAttributes(obj, propertyName) {
  var descriptor = getCustomPropertyDescriptor(obj, propertyName);

  return descriptor.get.$custom;
}

function getPropertyAttribute(obj, propertyName, attributeName) {
  return getPropertyAttributes(obj, propertyName)[attributeName];
}

function getCustomPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop) {
  var actualDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
  if (actualDescriptor && actualDescriptor.get && actualDescriptor.get.$custom) {
    return actualDescriptor;
  }

  var value = obj[prop];
  var descriptor = {
    get: function() {
      return value;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      value = newValue;
    }
  }
  descriptor.get.$custom = {};

  Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor);
  return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop);
}
```

Then :

```
var obj = {
  text: 'value',
  number: 256
}

setPropertyAttribute(obj, 'text', 'myAttribute', 'myAttributeValue');

var attrValue = getPropertyAttribute(obj, 'text', 'myAttribute'); //'myAttributeValue'
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pger957q/1/).